# What does int variable_name(0); mean?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm learning C in school and could not find any anything about this line of code

```
int numLetter(0);
```

We are currently learning about pointers. This line does not show up until the end of a for loop where we add 1 every time a case was satisfied.

```
++numLetter;
```

Going back to my question on the title. What does int variable(0); mean? Is it the same as initializing a variable like

```
int numLetter = 0;
```

EDIT:
Thank you for the response.
In the example I was given we are trying to do pointer arithmetic. The sample code is below:

```
const size_t arr_len = 7;
char name[arr_len] = "Marzian";
int numVow(0);

for (char *ptr = name; ptr < name + arr_len; ++ptr) 
{
    switch (*ptr)
    {
        case "A":
        case "a":
        case "E":
        case "e":
        case "I":
        case "i":
        case "O":
        case "o":
        case "U":
        case "u":
            +++numVow;
    }
}
```

I thought int numLetter(0); has something to do with pointer syntax. But like you guys have mentioned it is not a valid C syntax. My professor might have just mixed up the syntax when he made this example.
While I am here. Do you guys have any resources to understand pointer a lot better? Im not used to pointer/address I never used something similar when I was practicing python.

Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: Q: Could you update your post and show us more of the program?  What you showed is *not* valid C...

Comment: I don't think that's valid C code. Are you sure it's not C++?

Comment: Definitely looks like C++, in which case yes: it is an initialization, just like `int numLetter = 0;`

Comment: And it has nothing to do with pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This isn't a valid syntax in C language.**

**But in C++,** The value is being initialized to zero in the syntax given. You could say that:

```
int x(0);
int y = 0;
```

Both of the aforementioned statements are valid and equivalent to each other and they've nothing related to the pointers.